# Page vs Custom Post Type - which to use

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, metabox

I am creating a few pages (Company, Offices, Contact) and would like to have custom meta boxes for each of those pages. I want the meta boxes to be different for each page, and I don't know if that is possible to have meta boxes be unique for separate pages.

On the other hand, I don't know that custom post types are the right way to go either, because I don't want to have multiple Company, Office, and Contact posts.

What would be the right way to go about this so that they are single static pages and can have their own unique meta boxes in the admin?

Comment: What kinds of meta do you need? Almost sounds like you could accomplish what you need with page templates... but not sure about extra meta you need.

Comment: I need meta boxes so that the owner of the site can manage specific content for the different pages. For example, the company page will have an accordion style FAQ column. I would like to have a meta box where he can add multiple FAQ's and answers. But I don't want that showing up on each page. I can have different page templates, but that doesn't accomplish the task. The site owner needs to be able to edit this in the admin.

Comment: You can definitely do this with pages but it will difficult to do dynamically. That is, you'd have to hard-code your metaboxes by something like page-slug if that is an option. New pages would not have the boxes and a change of page name or page slug could break things.

Comment: Why not make a custom post type called FAQ that then runs on a special page template. That way there can be a dynamic amount of them, rather than many unwieldy WYSIWYG boxes.